# TypeError: when I attempt to pick out individual elements of an array

Tags: python, string, for-loop, set, typeerror

Here's my code that gives me a TypeError. Here, IndexOut is a predefined set along with data and datafinal. The format of the data in 'data' is JSON and as follows:

```
[{'timestamp': 1499159501922, 'coordinates': [12.919082641601562, 
77.65169525146484]}, {'timestamp': 1499159503930, 'coordinates': 
[12.918915748596191, 77.6517105102539]}, {'timestamp': 1499159506936, 
'coordinates': [12.918656349182129, 77.65177154541016]}, {'timestamp': 
1499159509002, 'coordinates': [12.918524742126465, 77.6517562866211]}, 
{'timestamp': 1499159511984, 'coordinates': [12.918295860290527, 
77.65178680419922]},
```

Here is my code running it. The above data has been altered quantitatively, but the format stays the same

```
for i in range(0, length-1):
    data.pop(IndexOut[i])

for i in data:    
    datafinal.add((i['coordinates']['latitude'], i['coordinates']
['longitude']))
print (datafinal)
```

Out.. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You should always include the Traceback (if there is one) with your questions.

Comment: Sure. My bad, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Elements within lists are indexed with numbers, and can't be indexed with strings unlike dictionaries. Latitude and longitude are elements 0 and 1 within each list, so the following should work:

```
datafinal.add((i['coordinates'][0], i['coordinates'][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'coordinates' is a length 2 array, and you're trying to access it as if it's an object, here:
`i['coordinates']['latitude'].`

Try using `i['coordinates'][0], i['coordinates'][1]`